# How to set 3 images on bootstrap left, center and right, As I am using loop on the images

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

All the images are coming at the center, I Even tried with Justify-content-between, But if from the backend only two images come to the edges and the center space is empty.

---

```
<div class="mm-mkt-BadgeRow row mx-auto"> 
    <sly data-sly-list.awardimages = "${aboutlo.Award_Image_LINK}">
        <div class="col-4 pl-3">
            <img src="${awardimages}" class="mm-mkt-BadgeOne" id="mm-mkt-badgeOne">
        </div>
    </sly>
</div>
```

---

Comment: did you try 'justify-content-between' ?  i mean, is it a typo maybe?

Comment: yeah, I tried with "justify-content-between". But only because of that, two of the images are coming on both sides and the center column is empty. for eg, in col-4 first image in second col-4 empty and third col-4 is again image

Comment: i think thats a different problem, see code below as example

Answer (score 0):

```css
.grid-row {
  display: grid ;
  justify-content: stretch; 
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
}

.grid-row div:nth-child(3n+2){text-align:center; }
.grid-row div:nth-child(3n+3){text-align:right; }
```

```html
<div class="grid-row">
    <div class"item1">1</div>
    <div class"item2">2</div>
    <div class"item3">3</div>
    <div class"item1">1</div>
    <div class"item2">2</div>
    <div class"item3">3</div>
    <div class"item1">1</div>
    <div class"item2">2</div>
    <div class"item3">3</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Individually, this will work, But in my code, there is a loop, how to handle that one

Comment: you could loop the rows, but i edited the example to use grid now.. (mind this may not work in ie11)